# How to implement real time video show or conference?

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, rtsp, rtmp, red5

Assume such a situation:
One video show or conference room has 1~5 publishers and 500~1000 subscribers. 
Subscribers watch publisher's video. 
Publisher's video and audio is captured in real time.

So I wonder, does this system(open source) exist? 
if not exist, how to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many solutions for your need.

If you doesn't want to host the solution yes one of them is Youtube Live, or Twitch if you want to publish a game.

But you can also host a Media server like [MonaServer](http://www.monaserver.ovh/), [FMS](http://www.adobe.com/fr/products/adobe-media-server-standard.html), [Wowza](http://www.wowza.com/), [Red5](http://red5.github.io/)... I work on the first one, it has P2P, it is free and open source so contact me if you are interested and want some help.

Comment: Thank you. But Youtube Live is not what I want. 
I'm interest to host a media server like MonaServer, Red5... But I have no experience in (rtmp or rtmfp protocol).  
So I have a few doubts:  
 How about the latency (video from captured by publisher to watch by subscriber )?  Compared with RTP?

Comment: Hi lingdhox. First you need a UDP Protocol (RTMFP, RTP or WebRTC) to avoid congestion. Then you must choose between cost-less P2P multicast or a publisher-subscriber solution that cost a large amount of bandwith and CPU. Sadly the second one offer the less latency because it does not imply peer redistribution. What you can do is to test RTMFP with or without [Netgroup](http://tomkrcha.com/?p=1526) using [this publisher sample](http://raspi.monaserver.ovh/MonaClients/VideoPublisher/) and [this player sample](http://raspi.monaserver.ovh/MonaClients/VideoPlayer/). (they are hosted on a Rpi)

Comment: WebRTC use RTP Protocol. But build a server based on WebRTC needs long time - -!.  I will test the sample. And how to turn off P2P mode, I'm no need P2P.   Think you very much

Comment: Just don't set a netgroup name, these samples use simple publish/play by default. If you think you will have 500 subscribers or more and don't want to use P2P feature I hope you have a big server and a very good bandwith!

Comment: haha. I know it need large bandwidth. But boss don't care, so I don't care also. For me, I will read and study RTMFP. Thinks for your open source project.

Answer (score 0):

It exists and it's called Youtube Live, https://www.youtube.com/channel/SBAaOjE-GIlRI and https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853700?hl=en

Comment: Thank you. But Youtube Live is not what I want. I'm interest to host a media server.